# PHP while statement within a while statement?

Tags: php, mysql

Db[db2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqhk2.png)
Code Sample so far only lists all the posts but shows only one Comment ?
Code I have so far only shows one comment ?

Please anyone with assistance I really need help am a noob at coding and trying my best. Thank you in advance

```
<?php
include("../db/db.php");
{

    /*if(isset($_POST["TimeLine"])){*/
    $queryposts = "SELECT * FROM post";
    $run_query = mysqli_query($con,$queryposts);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
        $post_id = $row["post_id"];
        $uid = $row["user_id"];
        $content = $row["content"];
        $like = $row["total_like"];
        $date = $row["date_created"];
        $uidpic = $row["profilepic"];
        $email = $row["email"];
        $pImage = $row["postimage"];
        $pVideo = $row["video"];
        echo "<b>POST: <b/><hr />".
            $content."<hr >"
        ;


        $querycomment = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE comment_id = $post_id";
        $run_queryb = mysqli_query($con,$querycomment);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_queryb)){
            $ComId = $row["comment_id"];
            $Comment = $row["comment"];
            $ComDate = $row["comment_date"];
            $ProfilePicpost = $row["profilepic"];
            echo "<b>Comment: <b/><hr />".
                $Comment."<hr >"
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're resetting `$row` in each while loop. Use different row variables for posts and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting same variable `$row` in inner loop. Change its name to anything else.

```
$queryposts = "SELECT * FROM post";
$run_query = mysqli_query($con,$queryposts);

while($posts = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){

    // Your post related code
    $post_id = $posts["post_id"];
    $uid = $posts["user_id"];
    // Use $posts instead of $row

    $querycomment = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE comment_id = $post_id";
    $run_queryb = mysqli_query($con,$querycomment);

    while($comments = mysqli_fetch_array($run_queryb)){

        // Your comment related code
        $ComId = $comments["comment_id"];
        $Comment = $comments["comment"];
        // Use $comments instead of $row

    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same result $comments only showing one result and does not loop to the next comment for one single post ?

Comment: show me your data from database. You can add screenshot of it in your question or add a link to sqlfiddle.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bress07ynezkt5p/AADmbwE8ZE-5M3YWYa4wo_-Ca?dl=0

Comment: Can you show me where you are getting duplicate comments? I just checked the output file on dropbox and if looks fine to me...

Comment: Just truncated the database to test again and it seems to be working sorry for the hassle I was able to code decently two years back but cant seem to remember how to anymore have loss of memory and lack of concentration so its a bit hard for me at the moment Thank you very much d.coder youre awesome